# SQL Joining and ordering invididual subjects by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

So I have two SQL tables, one is a customer address book and the other is a purchase log.

Customer Table

```
Cust ID      Cust Name
1            Adam
2            Brian
3            Charles
4            Dave
...
```

Purchase History

```
Customer ID         Price          Date
1                   $100           1996-01-20
1                   $200           1995-01-01
2                   $70            1999-05-22
...
```

What I want to see is the Customer name and the price of the most recent purchase. 
So the table should look like:

```
 Customer Name      Price      
 Adam               $100
 Brian              $70
 ...
```

I think I have a general idea of what functions to use (like order by, limit, and join) but I'm having trouble putting it all together.

To make matters worse, I need to figure out ways to deal with ties, meaning if there are multiple purchases by a customer on the same day. By default, I think it would just list the first price, but how do I make it so that it lists the highest price on that day? Or the average price?

Comment: I would prefer PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Postgres' `distinct on ()` operator:

```
SELECT distinct on (c.cust_id) c.cust_name, p.price, p.purchase_date 
from customer c 
  join purchase p ON c.cust_id = c.customer_id
order by c.cust_id, p.date desc, p.price desc;
```

By including the `price desc` in the `order by` Postgres will pick the highest price if there are two prices for one day.

Another option is to join to a derived table (which might be faster)

```
select c.cust_id, c.cust_name, p.price, p.purchase_date
from customer c
  join (
     select distinct on (customer_id) customer_id, price, purchase_date
     from purchase
     order by customer_id, purchase_date desc, p.price desc
  ) p on c.cust_id = p.customer_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how this solution (using `distinct on`) compares with the one below that uses window functions?

Comment: @Vic: typically `distinct on ()` is faster then an equivalent solution using window functions. Window functions give you more control over the definition of "distinct" for you query though and how you deal with ties.

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL way to rank records is `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` (both consider ties) or `ROW_NUMBER` (which doesn't).

The following query takes the last purchase day, and if there are several purchases it picks the record with the higher price. (And well if there are two purchases with the same highest price, one of the records is picked arbitrarily, but that doesn't matter.)

```
select
  customer.cust_name,
  ranked.price 
from customer
join
(
  select
    customer_id,
    price,
    row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by date desc, price desc) as rnk
  from purchase_history
) ranked on ranked.customer_id = customer.cust_id and ranked.rnk = 1;
```

The following query takes the last purchase day's purchases and computes the avarage price of these.

```
select
  customer.cust_name,
  avg(ranked.price) 
from customer
join
(
  select
    customer_id,
    price,
    rank() over (partition by customer_id order by date desc) as rnk
  from purchase_history
) ranked on ranked.customer_id = customer.cust_id and ranked.rnk = 1
group by customer.cust_id, customer.cust_name;
```

Comment: Is the `customer.cust_id` in the last line necessary?

Comment: No, it's just for the case when you have two customers with the same name, to get two separate rows instead of one. If you have a unique constraint on the name or just don't care, then this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put aside for a minute the ties issue you wrote, start with the basics, to get the name into the purchase table. This is a simple join:

```
SELECT c.name, p.price, p.date from purchase as p inner join customer as c
ON c.cust_id = c.customer_id;
```

This will give you a table containing all purchases, with the name.
Now on this you can add average, sum, max or whatever aggregation you want, for example:

```
SELECT name, date, MAX(price) from (
    SELECT c.name, p.price, p.date from purchase as p inner join customer as c
    ON c.cust_id = c.customer_id
) group by name, date;
```

Comment: But I want it to return the price of the most recent purchase only.

Comment: That will not return the latest date and price (only the _highest_ price for each date)